# Aucun retour en arrière ne sera possible

Tags: sens, expressions

Bonjour,

> Aucun **retour en arrière** ne sera possible.

Est-il possible d'employer "retour en arrière" dans le sens de *je ne pourrai pas revenir à mon ancienne vie*, *je ne pourrai pas vivre comme j'ai vécu auparavant* ? Dans les dictionnaires, on mentionne seulement que "retour en arrière" est synonyme de "flash-back".

Comment: Au fig.
♦ Retour en arrière. Action de se remémorer le passé. [Certains savants] demandent au sujet de se livrer à un retour en arrière et de décrire les états successifs de son moi au cours de l'expérience (Hist. sc., 1957, p. 1666).CIN. Retour en arrière. Procédé consistant à intercaler dans l'action un épisode qui a eu lieu à une époque antérieure. Synon. flash-back (rem. 2 s.v. flash). (Dict. xxes.). https://cnrtl.fr/definition/retour

Comment: @Lambie Merci, j'aimerais savoir s'il est possible d'employer ce tour au sens propre.

Answer (score 3):

Oui, « retour en arrière » a en général le sens de rétablir quelque chose qui était vrai avant. C'est le cas dans la phrase « Aucun retour en arrière ne sera possible ». C'est un sens figuré qui est proche du sens propre.

Le sens de *[flashback](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashback)* est rare et principalement [québecois](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8410265). En France, surtout quand il s'agit de cinéma, on utilise le plus souvent le terme anglais, d'autant plus que « retour en arrière » a aussi le sens d'une vidéo qui va en sens anti-chronologique ([exemple](https://www.repaire.net/forums/discussions/effet-de-retour-en-arriere-et-ralenti.149881/)).

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre réponse.